# rails routes filter request format

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an route which accepts all urls like this:

```
match "*name",            :to => "pages/landing_pages#get_page"
```

I want to filter this route to accept all requests expect requests with format jpeg, png and others. How can I modify this route to do this thing?